# PySpark: can I use a join as a lighter alternative to filtering?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with daily observations for a range of products and competitors. I want to only include the two last months of observations from competitors who we have observed at least 14 times the last month.

What I have done is I have made a list from temporary dataframe with competitors and product ids, who lives up to the rule, and then filter the original data frame accordingly.

However, I have found significant performance issues with using the filter(col in list) command, and I am looking for a different approach.
I was thinking of using an inner join, however then I would lose the observationa from the two month table.

So as shown in the image, are there any less heavy approach, like an inner join, to filter product_id to only be included if they are in the upper table?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOVxZ.jpg)

**EDIT**
So the below box of code displays the command, which I use to create the temporary dateframe, where the purpose is to use the concat_l as a list for later filtering. This command does work, however is slightly slow. This list has a length of 124k

```
    #Adding period column
df_spark_frequent = df_spark_raw.filter((f.col('date') >= dt_1m)
                               & (~f.col('store').isin('somestore', 'secondstore', ))) \
                      .withColumn('period', f.when(f.col('date') > dt_1m, f.lit('1m'))) \
                      .withColumn('xcount', f.count(f.col('period')).over(Window.partitionBy('store', 'product_id', 'period'))) 

                                      

df_spark_frequent = df_spark_frequent.filter((f.col('period') == '1m') & (f.col('xcount') > 13)) \
                                     .withColumn('concat', concat(f.col('store'), f.col('product_id')))


#Creating a list of all product ids and stores with >14 observations last month 
concat_l = df_spark_frequent.select('concat').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect() #This list has poor performance
```

The next command is where the code breaks, when I have to filter with the list:

```
df_spark_2m = df_spark_raw.filter((f.col('date') >= dt_2m)
                               & (f.col('sales_price') > 0)
                               & (f.col('store').endswith('dk')) 
                               & (~f.col('store').isin('somestore', 'secondstore', ))) \
                       .withColumn('concat', concat(f.col('store'), f.col('product_id'))).filter(f.col('concat').isin(df_spark_frequent.concat)) #this filter has a poor performance
```

Comment: Can you post the query where you feel using inner query will make you lose 2 month observation

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi please see edit, this is the code where I am looking for another approach.

Comment: if `df_spark_frequent` with only `concat` field is small, you can broadcast it and do an inner join. it'll be much faster than what you have -- currently, it is probably doing a cross join behind the scenes. you can check the process plan in spark UI or use `.explain()` to know more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df_spark_frequent.select('concat').distinct()` is a small dataframe, you can change the `filter()` to an inner join by broadcasting the smaller dataframe. This would increase the performance compared to your approach.

```
df_spark_2m = df_spark_raw. \
    filter((func.col('date') >= dt_2m) & 
           (func.col('sales_price') > 0) & 
           (func.col('store').endswith('dk')) & 
           (~func.col('store').isin('somestore', 'secondstore'))
           ). \
    withColumn('concat', func.concat(func.col('store'), func.col('product_id'))). \
    join(func.broadcast(df_spark_frequent.select('concat').distinct()), 'concat', 'inner')
```